# How to validate ten 0's(mobile no) in jquery ui plugin

Tags: jquery

here is my code

```
$("#contactForm").validate({
    submitHandler: function (form) {
        var submitButton = $(this.submitButton);
        submitButton.button("loading");

        form.submit();
    },
    rules: {
        name: {
            required: true
        },
        email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
        },
        subject: {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            minlength: 10
        },

        message: {
            required: true
        }
    },
    highlight: function (element) {
        $(element)
            .parent()
            .removeClass("has-success")
            .addClass("has-error");
    },
    success: function (element) {

        $(element)
            .parent()
            .removeClass("has-error")
            .addClass("has-success")
            .find("label.error")
            .remove();
    }
});
```

In the above code, `subject` is the mobile field I am concerned about. Please guide on the right path.

Comment: where is mobile no field?

Comment: please take sometime to write the question so that others may understand it fully. are you worried about the rule for `subjects`? where is the phone here?

Comment: Subject is mobile field

Answer (score 0):

in your rules, you need one for mobile number with `RegularExpression`...e.g.

```
subject: {
            required: true,
            regex: '/0{10}/'
}
```

I have updated based on @Praveen's suggestion.  If you want to limit to 10 digits, you could also have `^\d{10}$` as the RegEx.

**Update based on comment**:

You may want 10 numbers 1-9?, in that case try: `[1-9]{10}`

Comment: `/0{10}/` this would suit.

Comment: i want to validate 0000000000 's in mobile no ,if i enter 10 0's it accepting

Comment: Are you saying you want to stop users adding 10 0's ?  The question needs to be slightly clearer.

Comment: ya i want to validate the 10 0's when user enter 10 0's i have to show invalid number. then i want to focus the text filed when error occur.

Comment: I updated the answer yesterday, there's a regex there which allows digits 1-9.